# Remove file accidentally included in solution

Tags: visual-studio

At some point I accidentally included an ad-hoc `.sql` file in my Visual Studio solution. It keeps appearing in `find all` results, and I'd like to remove it.

It does not appear in the Solution Explorer, so I can't exclude it that way - the path to the file in the search box is to a location on my system.

Comment: So you *actually* just want to exclude a file from Find-in-Files search?

Comment: I guess so, but forever